# Difficulties in launching JBoss AS 7.1.3 final

Tags: java, batch-file, jboss

thanks for your future answers , helps and responses.
    I'm beginning in Jboss and Java;
    - I have installed JDK 8u121 in disk D: in  and i can use it effeciently;
    - now still in disk "D:", i have created a folder named "formation" where i did unzipped "jboss-as-7.1.3.Final" and i created an environment variable named "JBOSS_HOME" correctly
    - my machine caracteristics are RAM : 2GB, processor DualCore of 2.2GHZ
    - OS: windows 7, 32bits

```
Issue : when i launch Jboss from command line it doesn't complete; this is what is prompted:
/**
E:\formation\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\bin>standalone.bat
Calling "E:\formation\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
===============================================================================
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment
  JBOSS_HOME: E:\formation\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final\jboss-as-7.1.3.Final
  JAVA: D:\java\bin\java
  JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -
Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml
===============================================================================
08:54:41,967 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.3.GA
08:54:43,393 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
08:54:43,540 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.3.Final "Arges" dÚmar
re
*/

I even try to reach the administrative Ui through "localhost:8080" but still have nothing, please what can i do to make this work?
NB: i also check via "resmon" in`enter code here` windows to see if port 8080 is used but it isn't...
```

Comment: Your trace shows on the last line "JBoss AS 7.1.3.Final "Arges" dÚmar
re". That means that the server should be started... When you try to reach the administrative UI, you say "but still have nothing", what does it mean ? What kind of error ? 404, 500, other ? Can you try http://localhost:8080/admin-console and also try on port 9990 ?

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding: this what is prompt in google chrome: localhost n'autorise pas la connexion.
Essayez avec http://localhost-8080.com/
Effectuez une recherche Google sur localhost 8080.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Hello, to those who had the same problem, this is the  solution : for JBoss AS 7.1.3 , i install jdk 1.7 instead of jdk1.8, it works well now...